# Stub catch on redux-observable epic

Tags: rxjs, sinon, rxjs5, redux-observable, rxjs-dom

I`m trying to test the catch function of a rxjs observer but catch never run.

test.js

```
it.only('On fail restore password', () => {
    sandbox = sinon.stub(Observable.ajax, 'post').returns(new Error());
    store.dispatch(restorePasswordVi('prueba'));
    expect(store.getActions()).toInclude({ success: false, type: SET_RESTORE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS });
  });
```

Epic please see https://redux-observable.js.org/

```
export function restorePasswordViEpic(action$: Observable<Action>, store: Store) {
  return action$
    .ofType(RESTORE_PASSWORD_VI)
    .switchMap(({ user }) => {
      store.dispatch(blockLoading(true));
      return Observable
       .ajax
       .post(`${config.host}/auth/restore-password`, { user })
         .map(() => setRestorePasswordSuccess(true))
         .catch(() => {
           return Observable.of(setMessage('Se ha producido un error por favor intente de nuevo.'));
         });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stubbing of `Observable.ajax.post` needs to return an `Observable` that throws the error.

```
.returns(Observable.throw(new Error()));
```

All together:

```
it.only('On fail restore password', () => {
  sandbox = sinon.stub(Observable.ajax, 'post').returns(Observable.throw(new Error()));
  store.dispatch(restorePasswordVi('prueba'));
  expect(store.getActions()).toInclude({ success: false, type: SET_RESTORE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS });
});
```

Since your existing stub returns just an Error object itself (not an observable that throws an error) it should have caused an uncaught error to be thrown, something like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Observable.ajax.post(...).map is not a function
```

If you don't see any error like that when you run your test, you may have something swallowing errors silently somewhere, so something to look out for.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this many years later, Observable.throw is outdated and you can return an observable with a sinon stub using rxjs `throwError`. For example `exampleStub.returns(throwError(new Error()));`

Comment: @CarolynCommons Thanks! Not sure if you have the reputation points yet to edit posts, but if you do, feel free to edit the answer for the new pattern so you get the credit.